# Pass NSString value to another ViewController in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, viewcontroller, pass-data

I am trying to pass NSString value to another ViewController. But I get null instead of the value. Here is my code. 
FirstViewController.m:

```
NSString cellID = @"66";
    SecondViewController *apiViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
                 apiViewController.strMessage=cellID;
                 [self.navigationController pushViewController:apiViewController animated:YES];
```

SecondViewController.h:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController{
    NSString *strMessage;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *strMessage; 
@end
```

SecondViewController.m:

```
@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize strMessage;
NSLog(@"%@", strMessage);
@end
```

I did import. I assigned variable before pushing. But it anyway returns  null. How can I do this? Any tips, ideas. Thank you.

Comment: look into prepareForSegue.  https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepareforsegue

Comment: There are already so many topics for this subject.  What's the point of discussing an 8-year-old subject?

Comment: @ElTomato I tried them all and most of them wrote for nib connection. I do not need that.

Comment: An easy approach: Use segue and programmatically push a button.  You can hide the button.  Another easy approach: Create a class to store values.  Pass the value to this class and retrieve it with SecondViewController.  A challenging approach: Use protocol.

Comment: I don't think `@synthesize` is needed anymore.  Try putting the log in the `viewDidLoad` method of the pushed VC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SecondViewController *apiViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
 apiViewController.strMessage=cellID;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:apiViewController animated:YES];
```

And Print

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.strMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the property *before* you push the view controller.

```
NSString cellID = @"66";
    LineChartViewController *apiViewController = [[LineChartViewController alloc] init];
                 apiViewController.strMessage=cellID;
                 [self.navigationController pushViewController:apiViewController animated:YES];
```

Furthermore, you need to call the `NSLog` from within a function in your implementation. The `viewDidLoad` function, for example, as this is a UIViewController that is being pushed on a UINavigationController stack.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
SecondViewController *apiViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
     apiViewController.strMessage=cellID;
                     [self.navigationController pushViewController:apiViewController animated:YES];
```